# Files take up more space on one drive than another?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, windows-8.1, external-hard-drive

I have about 1.5TB of files on one external hard drive (a WD My Passport Slim).  I copied these files onto another drive (an internal drive, a WD Red, that I have attached externally via an adapter).  Both drives have the same setup - one partition that is formatted exFAT.

When I copied the files from drive A to drive B, I looked at drive B, and it says about 3TB is being used instead of 1.5TB!  I haven't put anything else on drive B, so the way it looks is that my files are taking up more space on drive B than on drive A, which makes no sense to me.

Is it possible that these files could take up more space on drive B than drive A?  If so, I would really appreciate an explanation.  If that isn't possible, then I would appreciate your advice for figuring out how almost double the space than should be is being used.  Thanks for helping solve this mystery!

P.S. If it makes any difference, I copied the files with [FastCopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, it can happen.

When partitioning's done, a chunk size is set, and then the partition is created with *n* chunks (where *n* is an improbably large number) in which to put files or pieces of files. Visualize the wall of mailboxes at your local post office.

The chunk is formally called a cluster, or allocation unit, as per [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/140365).

The bigger the cluster, the more space is wasted between the gaps of the ends of files, but then less space is wasted in keeping track of each of the spaces you have.

Comment: This was exactly the answer!  The allocation unit size on the destination partition was 1024k, vs. the source was 128k.  Unfortunately this means I have to repartition the destination, but problem solved :)  Thank you!!